# Type or namespace couldn't not be found. My database context has gone missing?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-4.0, dbcontext

I opened up a project I was working on this morning and I changed the target framework from .Net 4 client to .Net 4 to resolve an issue I was having with Moq.

After this I tried rebuilding my solution and I now get the following error:

> The type or namespace name 'AREDatabase' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I tried reverting back to .Net 4 Client with no luck, I've been trying to fix this for a while now with no luck.

Here is some of my code:

```
AREDatabase AREContext = new AREDatabase();
Rule StratRule = new Rule();
RuleService ruleService = new RuleService(new RuleRepository(new AREDatabase()), new Rule());
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Are you familiar with how to add a reference and or use a namespace..? where does `AREDataBase` exist or reside. you have some strange class names btw ..

Comment: The class was generated by the Entity Framework, all the references should be ok. Whats the problem with my class names? Im creating a rule editor

Comment: can you show how the namespace / class definition is.. perhaps you need to add it not only to the using up top, but also add the dll if there is one to the project references

Comment: I figured it out , somehow the class had vanished into thin air, I just had to copy and paste it form an old backup